# Why Scanner constructors with String encoding argument throw no UnsupportedEncodingException?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

Constructors of almost all classes from java.io and Formatter always throw *checked* `UnsupportedEncodingException` if `String encoding` is a constructor's argument.

But Scanner is totally different - it throws only *runtine* `IllegalArgumentException` if encoding argument is misspelled/wrong.

**Scanner class constructor seems to be the only one not to throw checked UnsupportedEncodingException in all java API (having String encoding a constructor's argument), throwing only runtime IllegalArgumentException.**

Why is that? Just a design/compatibility quirk or some deep reasoning behind that?

Comment: Almost impossible to answer other than by giving an opinion or make guesses. My guess is that this constructor was created in version 1.7, and that at that time, checked exceptions were already considered a bad idea, especially for such a case where the charset is, in 99% of the cases, hardcoded and the exception is thus guaranteed to never be thrown.

Comment: My non-informed guess is that UnsupportedEncodingException is hard to work with since it's a checked exception that needs to be handled explicitly (no one likes those). https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8183743 touches on this and introduces overloads that passes Charset objects instead of Strings, so maybe things can be better in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the only people who can answer this definitively are the people who designed the respective interfaces.

I think the decision was made deliberately.

The `UnsupportedEncodingException` exception is a bit of an anomaly:

- It is a subtype of `IOException` where encoding / decoding is actually orthogonal to I/O: consider the `String(byte[], String)` constructor.
- It is a checked exception, but there are convincing arguments that it should be unchecked:

  1. If `UnsupportedEncodingException` is actually thrown it is most likely the result of a programming error rather than a error that your application might be able to recover from.
  2. One of the most common use-cases is to give the string "UTF-8" as the encoding name.  The Java specifications guarantee that UTF-8 will always be supported by a compliant JVM, yet since the exception is checked, we still need to write a handler ... for a failure that cannot happen.

Given that these issues, I think the designers decided that it was better not to use `UnsupportedEncodingException` in `Scanner`, and to use an unchecked exception for the case where the requested encoding is not supported.